# Is there a way to check whether an object referenced by a WeakReference has a GC root?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, weak-references

Is there a way to check whether an object referenced by a WeakReference has a GC root?

I have a rather complex dynamic enumerator wrapper mechanism that should not hold any reference to a record after MoveNext() but should dynamically reload it if necessary to avoid Out-Of-Memory situations.

Now i want to create a unit test that ensures that those records are really fit for garbage collection and that doesn't change with some refactoring or other change.
=> Is there any way to get wether an object tracked by a WeakRefernce has a GCRoot without actually calling GC.Collect()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know, no.

In order to determine whenever the reference has GCRoot which is holding it alive, garbage collection algorithm needs to happen.

There's nothing wrong with `GC.Collect()` in unit tests, imo.

Comment: I guess if you cannot mock the GC just have to live with it in Tests.

Comment: Thought so. To rely on GC.Collect() to clean it up (on the first call) is a little bit based on optimisim and it doesn't exactly speed up the unit test suite.
I'll make sure the comment in code states exactly that noone should alter the class until he absolutely knows what he's doing :) Maybe plus a disabled unit-test for when that should happen. Thanks anyway~